# How is data in dimensional tables and fact tables of a data warehouse star schema?

Tags: attributes, dimensions, star-schema

I am studying data warehousing star schema and attribute hierarchies and I am getting confused because the examples of the book do not provide sample data on which to confirm my understanding of things.

In the book there is a sales data warehouse with a dimension for products that has the following attribute hierarchy:
PRODUCT(AllProducts, ByProductType, OneProduct)

See the image below:
[image]

What kind of sample data would go into the product dimension table?

PRODUCTS

---

AllProducts  ByProductType  OneProduct

---

?                 ?                       ?

?                 ?                       ?

?                 ?                       ?

If I'm not mistaken attributes are table columns or fields and I can't understand how would the data look like in this table

If you take the dimension Time from the same image, data can easily be sampled:

TIME

---

Year Quarter Month Week

---

2010 1           1        1

2010 1           1        2

2010 1           1        3

2010 1           1        4

One other thing I am confused about is how the data looks like in the fact table.  In the book it is stated that the fact table would deliberately contain duplicated data.  For example to come up with the sales figures of a whole year there is no need to aggregate weekly sales values on the fly because they would have already been calculated.  Now if in the time dimension I have a primary key value 1 that represents a year a quarter a month and a week all at once how can I hold the aggregate value of 1 whole year in the fact table?

TIME

---

ID Year Quarter Month Week

---

1  2010 1           1        1

SALES_FACT_TABLE

---

Sales TimeID ProductID

---

1000  1          ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greyish fields (AllProducts, OneProduct etc) in the figure are examples of *queries* on the products dimension, not attributes.

Attributes would be 
Product.Name, Brand, SKU, InternalName, DevelopmentStartDate, OnMarketDate ... whatever

Comment: Even the greyish fields of the time dimension?  Why isn't there a field in the time dimension named All_Years to resemble the All_Products field in the Product dimension?

Comment: I think so, yes. Attributes should be year, month, day, dayofyear, weekday, is_workday, is_national_holiday, etc

Comment: I think the diagram is a little misleading especially when it is read by a beginner and when read in conjunction with the text presented in the book.  However I got the grip now.  Thanks.